# yum update cannot find repo: base/7Server/x86_64; In centoOS-Base.repo need to put right links

Tags: yum, upgrade

I am unable to install any applications on Centos 7 and not able to use yum update as well
[yum update error[][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE42I.png). I checked the links as recommended from various other posts and they dont look right to me-because the links do not work. Any advice is greatly appeciated[[image: repo links][2]]

Answer (score 0):

1- Check your DNS : add google dns entry (8.8.8.8) to **/etc/resolv.conf** so you are sure that Centos repositories are resolved correctly.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

OR
add google dns entry to your netword card in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens<?>

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

Then restart network : `sudo systemctl restart network`

2- Check if the **mirrors** are accessible via Network :

```
ping mirrorlist.centos.org
curl -v 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?repo=os&arch=x86_64&release=7'
```

3- Uncomment the below line in **/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo**:

```
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
```

4- If you are using DHCP ; then execute the above :

```
ONBOOT=no
dhclient
```

5- Finally try to cleanup the cache :

```
yum clean all --enablerepo=*
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/*
```

Comment: step 1 done: added to /etc/resolv.conf I tried: sudo systemctl restart network---this did not work so I tried systemctl stop NetworkManager ; systemctl disable NetworkManager ; sudo systemctl restart network---this did not work

Comment: error found: Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[

Comment: Set DNS1=8.8.8.8 instead of DNS=8.8.8.8 then restart network.service